# DocID as a clickable column in Content Search web part

Tags: search, sharepoint-on-prem, content-search-web-part, document-id

We use the content search web part with a custom display template to show our documents throughout our intranet based on various criteria such as file type, language, Document Type (custom column) etc.

Now we have a request to display a column which contains the file's auto-generated Document ID. Furthermore this column should be clickable as well so the user gets re-directed to the file.

I am currently not able to figure out which property to use for this or if this requires a combination of maybe another custom column and a crawled property?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to ensure that the managed property is mapped correctly, as in [this](https://www.google.dk/amp/s/richardstk.com/2014/12/12/search-by-document-id-in-sharepoint-2013/amp/). 
As far as the link goes you can use a [direct link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/94d61015-a7e7-400a-b616-65e218bffb89/url-to-load-the-document-using-document-id?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious), or cheat an reuse the default link

Comment: Thx for answering. The first part we already implemented. I can search by DocID and it works fine. When I add DocID to the custom Property Mappings of the Content Search Web part it shows me a completely different ID - also the ID isn't clickable :( 
  
I fail to see what the second link can help me here? Which property would it be?  
     
>>cheat and reuse the default link  
Hmmm I didn't get that either :( sorry

Comment: It sounds like DocID is not mapped correctly. Try to inspect the properties returned by the search using the Sharepoint search query tool, https://www.koskila.net/2017/03/13/using-sharepoint-search-query-tool-investigate-search-index-issues-sharepoint-online/

Comment: Thanks ... It seems the property I was looking for is "dlcDocIdOWSTEXT" for the ID itself and "dlcDocIdUrlOWSURLH" for the URL. Also Great tool .. wish SharePoint was easier to use though ;)

Thanks!!

Comment: The SharePoint Search query tool should be bundled with any version of SharePoint  Great that it solved your issue